# Tcl/Tk : How to destroy root window when close toplevel window

Tags: tcl

When I execute the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec wish "$0" ${1+"$@"}

set w .main
toplevel $w
wm title $w "FOO"
```

I got two windows instead one.
I tried to hide wish "." window by :

```
wm state . withdrawn
```

but anyway when I close my toplevel window the main process still not finished.
My question is how to destroy wish window when I close toplevel window and completely finish the process?

Comment: Do you actually want 2 windows, or just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want 1 window, why not do your manipulations on the `.` window?

```
wm title . "FOO"
```

Then, when the user closes that window, your app will finish.

Comment: In this case I still have 2 windows with with "FOO" title. I want to left only toplevel window.

Comment: @rkaganov, it seems you don't get the idea that when `wish` starts (or you load the Tk package into `tclsh`), the first *toplevel* window is created automatically and is named "." (a dot). Hence if you only want one toplevel window just use this window named "." as Vinod showed, do not call `toplevel` which creates a second (unneeded) window. Closing "." will shut down the whole process.

Comment: Technically, closing the last toplevel just terminates Tk's version of the event loop. _Normally_ that leads to the Tcl interpreter closing down cleanly, but other options can happen too (e.g., if you're running Tk in multiple threads).

Comment: @Donal Good point, thanks.  I just had to add `bind . <Destroy> exit` to make sure my program closed while it was executing a `vwait` command.